# Transiting from Terminal 1 to 3 at Dubai airport

Tags: transit, airports, dubai

Good day,

i'm a Cameroonian student and I will be travelling from MADURAI to DOUALA and transiting through Dubai airport from spicejet flight to kenya airways. Will I need a transit visa to transit from terminal 1 to terminal 3?

Thanks for your assisitance.

Victor.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I'm not sure such page really answer the question (it is specific for Indian). And the answer seems to assume that not having a passport check is the same as not requiring transit visa (no, this is not true).

Comment: Having travelled through Dubai as an American with a South African wife, I can say that we at least were not required to have a transit visa. Neither, was one asked of us. In each case, we spent several hours in the airport for our layover. The last time we made this trip was about a year ago. In our party, we had both British citizens and Indian citizens. Does someone with more recent experience have input?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The answer provided on the related question is not limited to Indian passports. The answer here would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I put this search [Nigerian to Cameroon, transiting to UAE](https://www.emirates.com/ch/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=ng&destination=cm&transit=ae), and it give me the following:

- no visa need if you stay less then 24h (for transit at DXB)
- you need a confirmed ticket for the second flight.
- "*Passengers transiting through Dubai (DXB) with separate tickets and checked-in baggage do not have to clear immigrations and customs if they use the baggage transfer service offered by the airport. Fees apply.*". So it seems they requires that you uses a transfer service for your baggages. Or you should pass immigration, but so you may need to pay a 24h transit visa.
- and the COVID test results, but these could change, so you may check later, before you start your journey.